# Selecting one vs all records within group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table in SQL Server something like this (these records are coming from user input later I have to join this table with business table)

**Table A**

| id | group | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 4567876 |
| 2 | A | 5678988 |
| 3 | A | 9999999 |
| 4 | B | 1234567 |
| 5 | B | 6846677 |

For each group I want to select, If there is any entry for item 9999999 then select only this record else all records in that respective group. (e.g for given example in group A select item 9999999  and for group B all items)

| id | group | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | A | 9999999 |
| 4 | B | 1234567 |
| 5 | B | 6846677 |

I don't want to delete any records from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where a.item = 9999999 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from a a2
                  where a2.group = a.group and
                        a2.item = 9999999
                 );
```

You can also use a fancy trick with `rank()`:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by rank() over (partition by group
                      order by (case when item = 9999999 then 1 else 2 end)
                     );
```

Comment: Wow, it is working fine, could it be possible for other columns too within this table? Actually 9999999 represent all item in business table and i dont want any filter.

Comment: @Rajput . . . Please ask a new question with appropriate sample data and explanation.  I don't fully understand the question in your comment.